# Is there a way to move within a file in Vim similar to Emacs' Isearch?

Tags: search, vim

I've been using Vim for some time and I feel that I'm finally becoming somehow 'fluent' with it, but some of the feature listings, videos and other stuff I've seen (particularly Tim Visher's Vimgolf in Emacs series) really convinced me to give Emacs a try.

So for the past week, I've been using Emacs almost exclusively. I really miss some concepts I'm familiar with from Vim (mostly the action-movement style, things like `ci"` etc.), but one thing I really learned to love in Emacs is the way to move around a file with Isearch.

For example, if I wanted to move to a line where a function *fn* is called, and there were 2 other instances of 'fn' between the point and the position I want to move to, I'd do `C-s fn C-s C-s`. If I wanted to do the same in Vim, I'd have to do something like `/fn <CR> n n :noh <CR>`, which is nowhere as nice, so I'd probably just check the line number and do `#G wwwww...`.

So my question is: is there a way to emulate the efficiency of Emacs' movement with search in Vim? It doesn't have to use search, I'm just looking for something other than the cumbersome go-to-line and forward several words I described above.

Edit: Item 4 in [Effective Emacs](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs) describes nicely what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You've identified a few areas where vim's search is different than emacs' isearch, but there are quite a few others, and unless there's a plugin somewhere there will always be differences. But you can turn off the highlighting in a much simpler way by adding something like `nnoremap <leader><space> :noh<cr>` to your .vimrc. This lets you turn off the highlighting after the search via a \ followed by a space. Replace `<space>` with whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the mapping tip, definitely handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate Emacs with this keymap: `cnoremap <C-s> <Cr>/<C-p>`.

Though Vim has better ways for moving around than searching. Have you tried ctags?

I also recommend the [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) plugin for quickly moving around in the visible area of the text.

Comment: Thanks, EasyMotion is a little different, but with some custom mappings it pretty much satisfies my needs :)

Answer (score 2):

What is described in your link is exactly my primary mean of movement in Vim: `/foo<CR>nn` for incremental forward search and `?bar<CR>nn` for incremental backward search.

I don't see what is more efficient in `<C-s>foo<C-s><C-s>` and `<C-r>foo<C-r><C-r>`: that's even more keystrokes!

Anyway, I think that `:set hlsearch` is your problem. If all the matches are contained in the viewport that's OK but, as soon as *some* matches are hidden it becomes useless. I don't have `set hlsearch` so `/foo<CR>` is quite the opposite of inneficient for me.

Well, another problem is having (at least) three functions with the same name in the same file…

Vim has wonderful text-ojects: `}` or `]m` that are very useful when looking at some code for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
set incsearch
```

you can couple it with

```
set hlsearch
```

for even better results.

Also check out "*", it's pretty awesome.

Comment: I have both incremental search and search highlighting enabled (I use `:noh` most of the time, damn my OCD :), but using it to move to some point in the file just doesn't feel as efficient as in Emacs, so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Yes, and I use it as well, but the search in Emacs is awesome to simply move to any point in the file what is more than few lines away. [This](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs), item 4, describes nicely what I find so appealing about it.

Comment: @JakubLédl from that description you linked, I don't see what is different, at all, from Vim incsearch